# How can I plot only the month and the day (without the year) from this Pandas data-series?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I plot only the month and the date (without the year) in this chart?

Please find my code below:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data as web
    
style.use('ggplot')
    
from datetime import date, timedelta
days = 20
end = dt.date.today()
start = end - timedelta(days=days)
    
stock = web.DataReader('MSFT', 'yahoo', start, end)
    
spare = stock['High'] / stock['Open']
#print(spare)
plt.plot((spare - 1) * 100)
plt.show()
```

This shows the following chart:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the date index format of `spare` with [pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html)

```py
spare.index = spare.index.strftime('%m-%d')
```

[image]

Or you can convert Series spare to Dataframe and reset Date index to column, then change Date column format with [pandas.Series.dt.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

```py
spare = spare.to_frame().reset_index()
spare['Date'] = spare['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
plt.plot(spare['Date'], (spare[[0]] - 1) * 100)
```

Comment: thank you very much. Your response was very fast and exactly what I needed. I am really grateful.